# how to add multiple buttons in php

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to create a php form to record time took for support team to respond to a request. I added 3 buttons, one to hit when support team is contacted, 2nd to click when a call back is received. 3rd one is to submit data to a file.

The issue I am having is that when I hit the first button I get the data/time, but it wipes out all of the previous fields in the form. When I hit the second button the same thing happens.

Any advice on how to save the data/time without cleaning the form will be greatly appreciated. Please excuse me as I am new to this.

Here is the code:

```
            <th>
            <p>Vendor was contacted at:</p>
            <button name="start" >Start</button><br>


            <?php
            if (isset($_POST['start']))
            {
                $date_clicked = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');;
                echo " " . $date_clicked . "<br>";
            }
            ?>
            </th>
       </tr>
      <tr>
            <th>
            <p>Vendor responded at:</p>
            <button name="Response" >Response</button><br>


            <?php
            if (isset($_POST['Response']))
            {
                $date_clicked = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');;
                echo " " . $date_clicked . "<br>";
            }
            ?>
            </th>
       </tr>
     <tr>
        <th>
           <p><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'></p>
```

Comment: Where are you storing this info when it's `$_POST`ed? In a database, I assume?

Comment: I am trying to put this info in the Excel file.

Comment: HTTP is a stateless protocol thus variables do not perisist between two POST requests on the server, you have to include $date_clicked with the second POST requests made with the "Response" button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your page is working this way because `$_POST` data is only set once, upon submission, and is then immediately cleared. Since you're not currently storing the information in a retrievable manner on your server, i.e. in a database, you'll need to find a way to store it. As @Tyler-Collins pointed out, your best option is to use the `$_SESSION` array.

To initiate the `$_SESSION` array, use:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
```

Do this first, and on every page for which you'd like to continue using the `$_SESSION()` array. Then, in your "start" row:

```
<th>
<p>Vendor was contacted at:</p>
<button name="start" >Start</button><br>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['start'])) // if user just clicked the 'start' button
{
    $date_clicked = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $_SESSION['start'] = $date_clicked; // put 'start' time in session
    echo " " . $date_clicked . "<br>";
}
elseif (isset($_SESSION['start'])) // user didn't just click 'start', but 'start' value is already set
{
    echo " " . $_SESSION['start'] . "<br>";
}
?>
</th>
```

Do the same for the remaining row(s).

Comment: Better post ALL form values with each POST and display them using my solution. What if the customer wants to edit some field after posting for the first time? Your solution is terrible and shows lack of experience in production environments, no offense.

Comment: @thenchanter Your solution *doesn't* post all form values each time. Incidentally, it doesn't appear that OP's code allows for user edits after posting. Your answer deviates substantially from OP's original code. No offense :P

Comment: I tried to use your recommendation, but it still behaving the same way. May be I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Maybe. ;) What's the output of `var_dump($_SESSION);` *after* you've clicked the start button?

Comment: The start and response button is working now. Had a typo. However, my rest of the form is still getting cleared as soon as I hit the start button. In the other portion of the form, I am collecting name of vendor, contacting person name and ticket number. Any advice?

Comment: If you're processing that much data, I'd be inclined to push it into a database, and populate each field from a database call. Otherwise, you'll need to continue using the `$_SESSION` array for all fields.

Answer (score 0):

You must echo the posted value inside your form elements.

Example:

```
     <form method="post" action="">
     <input type="text" name="something" value="<?= isset($_POST['something']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['something']) : '' ?>" />
     <input type="submit" name="submit" />
     </form>
```

Comment: But this will only echo the `$_POST` value that was *just* submitted. OP needs those values to continue to be displayed even after second `$_POST`, third `$_POST`.

Comment: Sessions are your friend